# how to join svg polyline's one end to other end in html

Tags: html, svg

How would I change the markup below in order to join the endpoints of the polyline.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<svg height="200" width="500">
 <polyline points="20,20 40,25 60,40 80,120 120,140 200,180"
  style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:3" />
 </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Improved the grammar and clarity of the initial sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<polygon>` instead of `<polyline>`.

```
<svg height="200" width="500">
  <polygon points="20,20 40,25 60,40 80,120 120,140 200,180"
           style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:3" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the first point to the end of the list:

```
<svg height="200" width="500">
 <polyline points="20,20 40,25 60,40 80,120 120,140 200,180 20,20"
           style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:3" />
 </svg>
</body>
```